# Google Apps Script - How can one give out editor access to files based on a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet that has three columns. In column A I have the name of the files, in column B I have the URLs of the files, and in column C I have the email addresses of the users that need editing access.

So the user in C2 should be given access to file in B2, those in C3 to B3, etc. Can this be accomplished using addeditors() ?

How would I go about this?

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot image `the URLs of the files`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the sample values of it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for responding. I am not quite sure what you are asking. The URL’s are for other spreadsheets that are located in a folder. In other words, B2 is one Spreadsheet, B3 is another spreadsheet and so on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `The URL’s are for other spreadsheets that are located in a folder. In other words, B2 is one Spreadsheet, B3 is another spreadsheet and so on.`, I couldn't understand about the detail of URL you want to use because I thought that when the structure of your URL is known, the Spreadsheet ID might be able to be used for achieving your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike no worries. I should have been more specific and provided better details. So it’s my fault. But any script help is appreciated since that’s a language that I have problems with. 

Answer (score 1):

```
function addEditors() {
  // Get the values from the active sheet
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    // Adjust the range to suit table nb.file name col A not required
    .getRange('B1:C5')
    // Get the values
    .getValues()
    // destructure the array
    .forEach(([url, emailAddresses])=> {
      // Grant editor access 
      // nb addEditor expects a string; addEditors expects an array
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).addEditors(emailAddresses.split(','))
    })
}
```

Comment: this amazing. I do have two questions. 1) if i have two emails (editors) for the same sheet, is it possible to include them in the same cell under column C? i tried it and it didn't work but tt's possible that i used the wrong syntax as I used a comma to split the emails. And 2) is it possible for a message to be sent to the users? Normally when access is given manually you have the option to add a message so the user is notified. Thank you! You have been very helpful!!

Comment: I believe the default setting is the user will be notified when you grant access. If you require more control of fie sharing look at DriveApp